# Python re.split ',' around "" and ''

Tags: python, regex

```
string = "\"Hello, \", 'world!'"

a = re.split(idk, a)

print(a)
```

Here what i want:

```
>>> ['Hello, ', 'world!']
```

but i am not know how do it

Comment: By what rule is `, ` after `\"` removed and not after `Hello`?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what your string actually *stores*. Try not to get lost in all of the backslashes and nested quotes. `print` out your string to see the actual characters in it, and see if that matches your expectations, because based on the expected output I'm guessing that it doesn't.

Comment: what if i have file where text like "Hello, ", 'world' and Python reading this like "\"Hello, \", 'world'"

Comment: Again, Python isn't *reading* it as anything. It's reading exactly what you give it. It might *show* you some backslashes in the REPL for convenience, but those aren't really there. They're to make things less ambiguous. `print` to see the actual contents of the string.

Comment: @DenisC So you want to extract all the strings between matching quotes? If so, can these quoted strings contain embedded quotes (e.g. `'"We said "yes", they said "no"..."'`)?

Comment: @ekhumoro '\'We said "yes"\', \'they said "no"\''

Answer (score 1):

You can have this output but the code for that is not very beautiful

First the regex:

```py
string = "\"Hello, \", 'world!'"

a = re.split("\"|'|\", '", string)

print(a)
```

Give this output:

```py
['', 'Hello, ', ', ', 'world!', '']
```

Now you need to filter the array:

```py
a = list(filter(lambda s: len(s) > 0 and s != ', ', a))

print(a)
```

And you have the desired output:

```py
['Hello, ', 'world!']
```

Comment: i wanted from "\"Hello, \", 'world!'" to ['Hello, ', 'world!'] not like ['', 'Hello, ', ', ', 'world!', ''] and if input was "\"a,\", 'b'"?

Comment: Yes it's for that you need to filter the array, but you're right if input was `"\"a,\", 'b'"` the output we'll be only `['a,']` so you can change filter like this `a = list(filter(lambda s: len(s) > 0 and s != ', ', a))` and you have the desired output `['a,', 'b']`